# How to convert GCM Response(Bundle) into JSON

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi i am receiving the GCM Notification. But i think it is in the form of Bundle. Now Problem is how to parse it so that i can use the value.
I am receiving the String by using

```
String message1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
```

But when i use the

```
String message1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

It return null.

When i try to convert it into JSON it give Error. I am receiving the notification in the form of

```
Received: Bundle[{id=12,android.support.content.wakelockid=1,collapse_key=do_not_collapse,from=18.......51}]
```

How to get the value of id From the Bundle.

Comment: Hmm, it is called `id` so what about using `getStringExtra("id")`?

Comment: Sorry i have edit the question.

Comment: post your full message body...

Comment: It might be structured as a Bundle object or a JSON object or even something completely different.Please post the entire String that you are receiving so that it might help your cause.

Answer (score 1):

try this :-

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

    String rowid =intent.getExtras().getString("ur key")
}
```

Comment: It give Error unexpected Received

Comment: it give rowid = null and message = Received: Bundle[{id=12,android.support.content.wakelockid=1,collapse_key=do_not_collapse,from=18.......51}]

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
String jsonData = extras.getString( "com.parse.Data" );
String ID=new JsonObect(jsonData).getString("ID")
```

or have you tried getStringExtra("Id")? what result did you get with this?

Comment: Thanks for Answer but Sorry, in Response the position of id is not fixed. So i can use the 0 position for id.

Comment: Can you plz post other variants of the string? I mean, with different format.Moreover, are you using native webservices for GCM?